# Does The Hulk need oxygen to survive?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, powers

I'm not very familiar with the different versions of The Hulk. However, in general does he need to breathe oxygen in order to survive?

Would it be possible to kill him by propelling him into outer space?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**No, he does not depend on oxygen to survive.**

Or more correctly, he does not require an external oxygen source to survive.

According to [Marvel Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Hulk_%28Bruce_Banner%29)

> The Hulk's body also has a gland that makes an "oxygenated per fluorocarbon emulsion", which creates pressure in the Hulk's lungs and effectively lets him breathe underwater and move quickly between varying depths without concerns about decompression or nitrogen narcosis.

In Hulk 77 (from 2005), Hulk has just fought a giant squid, and reflects on how he just survived such a prolonged battle underwater.

He realizes that his body has adapted to allow him to breathe underwater.

[image: hulk figures out he can breathe underwater]

I can't find exactly which issue this is from (I believe it is from the prologue to World War Hulk), but The Hulk is in space when his breathing device is damaged and his body alters itself to adapt to the environment.

[image: comic scan]

Comment: Ok, I'm not saying your wrong, but... WTF? How do you *adapt* to no oxygen?

Comment: @Jersey it's the hulk ffs.  This is the guy that fought the SENTRY to a standstill.  He can literally do anything that he wants.

Comment: The Hulk is basically the toughest thing in the Mavel universe.
There is a comic, where in the end, there is nothing but the Hulk, and a swarm of metal locusts left.

Comment: @Acolyte Except... well, gravity. Has anyone ever bothered with mindgames with the Hulk? You would think a Zero-G environment would be the way to go. A vaccum might do something (no friction = no resistance). Perhaps a *lesser* environment might make the Hulk weaker, as he seems to get stronger the tougher the situation.

Comment: @Jersey - "Has anyone ever bothered with mindgames with the Hulk".   Ummmm...well...i think Starfox...kinda tried...once...

Comment: @acolyte I never heard of STarfox... unless we're talking the Nintendo character... I take it that particular incident went 'smashingly'? (couldn't resist)

Comment: @Jersey no...no we're not...sadly  http://www.cracked.com/article_16403_the-7-most-hilariously-mismatched-superhero-battles.html

Answer (score 2):

The Hulk adapts to his surroundings, [*World War Hulk*](https://majorspoilers.com/2007/06/15/world-war-hulk-4/) explains it. I have graphic novels where he developed gills to breath under water. Hulk survived the sun and destroyed all X-Men, Hulk buster teams, and we still have this convo... He can't and won't die...

Answer (score -2):

The correct response is that the Hulk cannot die due to a lack of oxygen.

In the past, the comics explained that he was holding his breath for extended periods of time. But now, it is explained that he never realized that he could have his body “adapt” to conditions of no oxygen.

Comment: As for your actual answer here it could be greatly improved by [edit]ing in some evidence. However, your final paragraph appeared to have been asking a new question. If this is the case please ask it as a new question, if it wasn’t and I misread and was relevant to your answer please edit it back in and maybe expand on it a bit to clarify what you mean!

Answer (score -3):

The Hulk cannot be killed by anything that cannot kill him instantly. Period.

If he is exposed to a negative stimulus, for any significant amount of time, and allowed to adapt, he WILL adapt. This includes lack of oxygen, exposure to any radiation, heat, cold, anything. Given time, Hulk Smash it.

He's not invulnerable by any means, but gets closer and closer the longer he remains angry and exposed to an aggressor.