# Could the Hulk starve to death?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

Let's say someone managed to get the Hulk into space and left him there. Is there anyway he could die from starvation if left out there long enough?

Comment: Well, he [doesn't need oxygen](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40059/does-the-hulk-need-oxygen-to-survive/54435#54435). It's conceivable his body could adapt to photosynthesise (green!) or acquire other hand-waving ability so he doesn't require food.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes... well, most likely.**

Although never portrayed consistently, The Hulk has been shown to require food on numerous occasions. While his gamma-irradiated physiology most likely affords him a certain resistance to starvation, the very fact that he still experiences hunger in Hulk form would seem to indicate that he could, in fact, eventually starve to death.

[image]

[image]

It has been speculated that The Hulk possesses a nearly-limitless source of energy within himself. Even so, the simple fact that Banner experiences hunger in Hulk form still means that his Hulk physiology requires sustenance of some kind - whether it be food or metabolized energy from unknown sources. Either way, his body - The Hulk's body - is capable of starvation once all forms of sustenance are removed.

Comment: Assuming that the body that feels hunger means it can starve. A person can be given all nutrients through IV, nothing through the stomach, and live. They would still feel hunger.

Comment: @cde yes, but if you can feel hunger, it means that your body requires sustenance - regardless of how it's provided. I'll add something to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

#### No. It seems unlikely given the parameters of starvation, that the Hulk could starve to death. Overall, the Hulk has been portrayed as self-sustaining, requiring neither food, nor water, nor energy from any source other than what has powered his superhuman abilities. The Hulk has the ability (handwavium from lazy writers) to adapt to whatever conditions he finds himself in.

The Hulk has been explained as having an infinite source of energy from as far back as the Secret Wars II #2 when he is scanned by the Beyonder. This supposedly explains his limitless rage and ability to continuously grow more powerful and damage resistant, the angrier he becomes.

[image]

**Adaptation:** The Hulk is capable of adapting to inhospitable environments whenever it becomes necessary, the angrier the Hulk gets, the faster he adapts. Given that he can recreate his personal mass at will, it would seem strange for him to be able to die from starvation.

[image]

**Self Sustenance:** Presumably from wherever the Hulk's superhuman energy to create his extra mass, the Hulk's physiology allows him to survive indefinitely without food, water, air or sleep after he has adapted.

[image]

[image]

*from Defenders #68*

- **Hulk rides a ship to Morvania, a trip of three weeks at sea, sealed in a box without food or water. It's not an infinite amount of time, but he didn't seem any worse for the trip.**

**Underwater breathing:** The Hulk has the ability to breath under water because his glands develop an oxygenated per-fluorocarbon emulsion which fills his lungs and equalizes the pressure.

[image]

*from Sentry Vol.2, #3*

[image]

*from Incredible Hulk #11*

Comment: Dates (even just a year) would be awesome for the referenced comics/images. I know it's too late to add them now, but if available in the future it's always interesting to see the character/comic evolution

Comment: The comics and their points of origin are capable of being searched for.

Comment: I tried for "Incredible Hulk #11" and got apparently 3 volumes of "Incredible Hulk", with links to October 1982 & August 2012, neither of which showed a bald Hulk. Image search didn't help either, but an Aug 2012 cover of #9 looked like he was floating underwater... "Search by Image" reveals [this page](https://plus.google.com/photos/+GuilleSGOTTLOSEN/albums/5754881018051195729) that says it's actually from the August 2012, but Issue 9, not 11. If you're already finding the images when originally posting the answer, it would be awesome to add a date too if it's available right there. Thanks!